# How to get Telerik radgrid row index value on OnBatchEditCellValueChanged command when grouping is applied?

Tags: c#, jquery, telerik, telerik-grid

```
CellValueChanged_grdRoundRobinGroupMatch: function (sender, args) {
 var data = sender.get_batchEditingManager()._getCellDataToOpenEdit(sender.get_batchEditingManager().get_currentlyEditedCell());
    var row = data.row;
    var rowIndex = row.rowIndex - 1;
}
```

This above code is working fine when there is no grouping applied. But when some grouping is applied 
the rowindex value got changed. any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own solution. I didn't get the row on batch edit mode so I take the row on selected items basis. I also set AllowMultiRowSelection="false" and I did that this way-

```
CellValueChanged_grdRoundRobinGroupMatch: function (sender, args) {
 var masterTableView = sender.get_masterTableView();
    var selected = masterTableView.get_selectedItems();
    var rowIndex = selected[0]._itemIndex;
}
```